# How to access static files from deeper link? node js

Tags: node.js, express

from `localhost:3000/home` I can access the static folders with no problem,
but when I'm trying from a link like this `localhost:3000/b/test` it won't work,
Why?

```
app.use(express.static('public/css'))
app.use(express.static('public/ejs'))
app.use(express.static('public/js'))
app.use(express.static('public/imgs'))
app.use(express.static('public/uploads'))
```

[image: Project Tree]

Comment: If you want the path to be like that you need to do `app.use(express.static('public'))`. Otherwise with your current setup you will need to make a link to `localhost:3000/test` without the `b`

Comment: Alternatively, you can also do `app.use('/css', express.static('public/css'))`, `app.use('/js', express.static('public/js'))` etc.

Comment: and then how will i reach to the files?
lets say ```<img src="img.png"/>``` or  ```<img src="uploads/img.png"/>``` because they both not working

Comment: ```GET http://localhost:3000/b/uploads/test.png 404 (Not Found)``` - this is the browser's error